# Check if a string is percentage value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write this in C#. The requirement is very straightforward - check if a string input is a value within the range from 0 to 100.

1. I want to make sure the string is either an integer value in the range of 0 to 100 or
2. a double that's within the same range as well.

So for example, these are the accepted values:

```
0
50
100 
0.1
50.7
100.0
```

I checked the double.parse method here but not sure if it's the one I'm looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-double-tryparse(system-string-system-iformatprovider-system-double@)

The reason is that it can also parse string like this one: 0.64e2 (which is 64)

Is this something that can be achieved with built-in library already?

Comment: This does not make any sense.  The numbers posted can be either a value or a percentage.  0.1% = 0.001.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, which part is not making sense? Maybe I shouldn't say percentage. I updated my original post.   Also, if the string is "0.1%", I would want my method to return false.

Comment: _Is this something that can be achieved with built-in library already?_ Built-in functions are for common issues. This is not. You can test the string with Contains or even IndexOf for the % sign and convert it to a double and then test the range. What is going wrong? Where is your code?

Comment: Use `Single.Parse` method with `NumberStyles` that you need, there are plenty of them (including `AllowExponent`) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-7.0

Comment: @TaW there's no code as I'm only thinking how I can verify a string has only numbers, and decimal points only, and also make sure it's within the range of 0 - 100

Comment: @DarkChocoBar Check it can be parsed, using the NumberStyles option in the Double.TryParse method that you've already found, and if it can then check it is in the required range.

Comment: Use Decimal.TryParse to determine if its a valid number. If so, cast it then check the range.

Comment: There is no rule that you can use to say if a number is a number or a percentage.  You are just randomly deciding trying to make a rule when there is no rule.  You are just going to get randomly results.  You cannot fix errors input data when people make mistakes by guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote you a little snippet:

```
// C# function to check if string is a percentage between 0 and 100
public static bool IsPercentage(string s)
{
    // regex check if s is a string with only numbers or decimal point
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d+\.?\d*$"))
    {
        double d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
        return d >= 0 && d <= 100;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also returns false if the string contains % or has exponential (e).

Comment: Simplified version: `return Double.TryParse(s, out double d) && d >= 0 && d <= 100;`. With pattern matching: `return Double.TryParse(s, out double d) && d is >= 0 and <= 100;`

Comment: this will still return true if number has exp. representation like mentioned 0.64e2.
I thought this was the main problem of the Q...

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Good catch, didn't see that in the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Some potential snags: 1) Some people omit the leading zero, e.g. ".5" instead of "0.5". 2) TryParse would be better because a long string of digits (e.g. `new string('2', 309)`) will pass the regex but throw an error for Convert.ToDouble. 3) "\d" matches characters such as "०१२३४५६७८९" (and *many* more) unless you use `RegExOptions.ECMAScript`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton lol GitHub co-pilot wrote that regex for me; I don't know regex.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding of the Q was correct and exponential representations like mentioned "0.64e2" is unwanted:

```
static bool IsPercentage(string s)
{

  if (Single.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign |
        NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out Single n))
          return n >= 0 && n <= 100;

return false;
```

}